# How do I rotate links in a list of links once each day in Php

Tags: php, loops, variables, random

PHP question...

I have a list of 10 links that I want to rotate the order of, once each day so that:

- Day 1 echos Link 1, Link 2, Link 3, etc.
- Day 2 echos Link 2, Link3, Link 4, etc.
- Day 3 echos Link 3, link 4, link 5, etc.
- Etc.

This simply loops on each day so that Link 1 will follow after Link 10 to repeat the cycle. Thank you.

Comment: Hi,  you will get more and better responses if you show us what you've already tried and what you're stuck on. Questions that simply ask us to write your code for you don't get received to well.

Comment: Thank you Steve. You are right Point taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$links = ['http://link1', 'http://link2',  'http://link3', 'http://link3', 'http://link4']; // etc
$offset = date('z');
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
   $index = ($i + $offset) % count($links);
   echo $links[$index]."<br>";
}
```

The modulo operation `%`  keeps the $index inside the range of the array.

Answer (score 2):

If you store your links in an array you could use date("z") that will return the date as a number between 0 and 365.

```
<?php
    $myLinks = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
    $todaysStart = date("z") % count($myLinks);

    if($todaysStart != 0){
            $arrayBuffer = array_slice($myLinks,$todaysStart,sizeof($myLinks)-1);
            $arrayBuffer = array_merge($arrayBuffer,array_slice($myLinks,0,$todaysStart));
    }else{
            $arrayBuffer = $myLinks;
    }
```

The number for today is 293.
293 % 10 = 3 so we "shift" the elements three spots to the left and concats the first three elements at the end.

 Now you can loop through it with foreach or any other type of loop.